# Saving part of window.location in jquery variable on page load

Tags: jquery, window.location

If I have one the following:

```
example.com/test1
example.com/test1/
example.com/photo/test1
example.com/photo/category/test1/
```

(you get the point)

How can I end up with test1 as a variable on load in jquery?

`window.location.pathname` gives me the entire /photo/category/test1/ not only test1

Many thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function that will extract the last path element:

```
function getLastSegmentOfPath(url) {
    var matches = url.match(/\/([^\/]+)\/?$/);
    if (matches) {
        return matches[1];
    }
    return null;
}

var endPath = getLastSegmentOfPath(window.location.href);
```

Working test case and demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/9GXSZ/

The regex works like this:

```
\/  match a forward slash
()  separately capture what is in the parens so we can extract just that part of the match
[^\/]+ match one or more chars that is not a slash
\/?$  match an optional forward slash followed the the end of the string
```

In the regex result (which is an array):

```
matches[0] is everything that matches the regex
matches[1] is what is in the first parenthesized group (what we're after here)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like the following will work, if you want to find the last part of the pathname:

```
var path = window.location.pathname.split('/');
path = path.filter(function(x){return x!='';});
var last_path = path[path.length - 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var parts = "example.com/photo/category/test1/".split('/')
var url = parts[parts.length - 1] ? parts[parts.length - 1] : parts[parts.length - 2];
```

(the `?:` takes care of the last `/`)

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascripts [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) and [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) functions:

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var index = url.lastIndexOf("/");
var lastbit = url.substr(index);
```

This get's the URL, finds the position of the last `/`, and returns every thing after this positon.

**Edit** (see comments):
To exclude trailing slashes (eg: *category/test/*), and the first slash use:

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var index = url.lastIndexOf("/");
var lastbit = url.substr(index);
if (lastbit == "/"){
     url = url.slice(0, - 1); 
     index = url.lastIndexOf("/");
     lastbit = url.substr(index);
}
lastbit = lastbit.substring(1);
```

Comment: Doesn't handle the variability in the trailing slash.

Comment: @jfriend00 You can check if the lastbit variable is NULL, if so remove the last character from url variable and repeat

Comment: @Gab `lastbit = lastbit.substring(1);`